# Why is Foo not a function when I defined it?

Tags: javascript

I'm guessing this is some sort of "scope" issue but I want to understand why this is the case.

```js
function foo(){
  return true;
}

function bar(){
  var foo = foo();
  console.log(foo);
}

var foo = foo();
console.log(foo); //returns true as expected
```

But when I do the following

```js
function foo(){
  return true;
}

function bar(){
  var foo = foo();
  console.log(foo);
}

bar(); //returns Uncaught TypeError: foo is not a function
```

It seems that a variable name cannot be the same as a function name.  But that isn't true is it?

Comment: You've just overwritten `function foo()` with `var foo`, and since it's hoisted to the top before assigning the value, `foo` is `undefined`

Comment: Recommend removing `bar` from the first example entirely. You never call it, so it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two concepts which should help you understand this:

The first is **shadowing** which means that if you define a variable name inside a scope, it will hide the same variable name (or function name) from a parent scope.

The second is **hoisting** which causes any variable declarations to be moved to the top of the local scope.

This code

```
function foo(){}

function bar(){
  var foo = foo();
  console.log(foo);
}
```

is equivalent to this

```
var foo;//will initialize foo to undefined
foo = function(){}

var bar;
bar = function(){
  var foo;//will shadow parent foo and initialize foo to undefined
  foo = foo(); //fails because you are trying to call an undefined object
  console.log(foo);
}
```

Hopefully, this makes it obvious why 'foo is not a function'. Your bar function is declaring a new foo variable (which hides the global one inside the bar scope) and then tries assigning this variable by calling itself.

You can read more about the intricacies of `var` here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: This is the best answer so far. You should elaborate though on why the first version does work. Also a link to read more about hoisting would be nice.

Comment: It's not down to hoisting. It's just down to *shadowing*. `let` isn't hoisted, for instance, and yet V8 (the JavaScript engine in Chrome) complains if you swap out `var` with `let`, because `foo` falls in the temporal dead zone.

Comment: also true, I think both concepts are important to understand the behaviour though, so I've added shadowing to the answer.

Comment: Just to round things out: It's not just V8, a note at the top of [§13.3.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-let-and-const-declarations) covers this: `let` variables are created when the lexical environment is created (like `var` ones are), but cannot be accessed (the temporal dead zone) until the `let` is processed in the step-by-step handling of the code. So `let foo = foo();` will fail with `foo is not defined`.

Comment: updated my example to be hopefully clearer to understand.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, the names created by function declarations like your `foo` declaration are very much the same as variables. And so your second example fails for the same reason that this example alerts 2, not 1:

```
var a = 1;
function bar() {
    var a = 2;
    alert(a);
}
```

...because the `a` inside `bar` *shadows* the `a` outside `bar` that would otherwise be in scope since `bar` closes over it.

> It seems that a variable name cannot be the same as a function name. But that isn't true is it?

A variable name can indeed be the same as a function name, but if you do that in a nested scope (as you have), the variable name *shadows* the function name.

In your `bar`:

```
function bar(){
  var foo = foo();
  console.log(foo);
}
```

...the `foo` in `foo()` is the **variable** declared in `bar`, not the function declared in the outer scope. As such, it has the default value variables have (`undefined`), which can't be called, so you get the error.

In a comment you've asked:

> Since that is the case that i'm overwriting foo in the second example, aren't I also overwriting it in the first example?

No, and that takes us back to the first statement above: The name created by a function declaration is very much like a variable. As such, if you declare a function, then **later** declare a variable with the same name, the variable declaration is ignored. So your first example is interpreted as though there were no `var foo` at all at global scope. So `var foo = foo();` is really `foo = foo()`, which works just fine, calling `foo` and then using the return value to update `foo`. (Doing it again would fail, because the value the function returns isn't callable.)

Comment: Thank you, this was equally helpful.  I wish I could mark more than 1 as the answer.  It looks my error was that I was searching for "scope" issues when it was more specifically "hoisting".  Thank you (SO community) for providing such great answers!

Comment: just saw your comment on Patricks that it isn't actually hosting.  I'll check back to make sure i'm marking the correct answer.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Check the commend on the code

```
function foo(){
  return true;
}

function bar(){
  var foo = foo(); // before calling foo(), foo is defined as a variable, so foo is not a function anymore in this scope.
  console.log(foo);
}

bar(); //returns Uncaught TypeError: foo is not a function
```